# Near Future Precipitation and Temperature estimations?

Tags: temperature, hydrology, precipitation, climate-models, climatology

I was wondering if anyone here is familiar with temperature and precipitation estimation?

I need to estimate P and T from April to July 2016. I am planning to use excel to do the calculation because  I am not familiar with programming languages.

What options do I have for the calculations? are there ready formula that I can use to estimate T and P? what historical based models are there for such problem?

Thanks,

Comment: You can get historical data at ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/ if that helps.

Comment: In which region (city, country?) do you need P and T values? Most of the time you can find some historical data online.